# How to wait for async function to end?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, http-post

I have a widget class that loads user's messages from backend and shows it on the screen. I am calling my asynchronous function `getConversations` in widget class' build function to get user's messages. But I couldn't figure how to wait for that function to end. It ends after my build function returns empty list. Here are my codes:

getConversations:

```
Future<List<Conversation>> getConversations(BuildContext context) async {
  Map<String,dynamic> conversations;
  try{
    var getMessagesUrl=Uri.http(BackendBaseURL,'/user/messages/');
    print('before post');
    var response = await http.post(getMessagesUrl,body:convert.jsonEncode({'id':_userID}));
    print('after post');
    if(response.statusCode==200){
      conversations=convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String,dynamic>;
      print(conversations);
      return conversations.entries.map(
        (conversation) => Conversation(
          conversation.key, 
          conversation.value.map(
            (message) => Message(message['message'],message['sent_by_user'],message['send_date'])
          ).toList().cast<Message>()
        )
      ).toList();
    }
    else
      showErrorDialog(context, 'Sunucuya bağlanılamadı.');
  }
  on Exception catch(e){
    print(e);
    showErrorDialog(context, 'Sunucuya bağlanılamadı.');
  }
  return [];
}
```

Build function:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  List<Conversation> conversations=[];

  getConversations(context).then((value) => conversations=value);
  print('then: '+conversations.toString());

  //Need to wait getConversations function here before continuing

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(this._username),
    ),
    body:Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
          
      ]..addAll(conversations),
    ),
  );
}
```

And my output goes like this:

```
I/flutter ( 3034): before post
I/flutter ( 3034): then:[]
I/flutter ( 3034): after post
I/flutter ( 3034): {belkanahmet: [{message: ii sn, sent_by_user: true, send_date: 2021-07-02T15:32:54+03:00}, {message: nbr, sent_by_user: false, send_date: 2021-06-26T21:44:58+03:00}]}
```

Comment: Check out [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: @quoci That solved my problem, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FutureBuilder class is what I was looking for (thanks to @quoci)

With FutureBuilder I was able to return different widgets for different data values. In my case after I get a response from my API I was able to return a different body from my build function. Here's the working code:

getConversations:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    List<Conversation> conversations=[];

    getConversations(context).then((value) => conversations=value);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(this._username),
      ),
      body:FutureBuilder(
        future: getConversations(context),
        initialData: [],
        builder: (builder,snapshot){
          if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting) //While waiting for response return this
            return Center(
              child:CircularProgressIndicator()
            );
          return Column( //After getting response return this
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              
            ]..addAll(conversations),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Stream Builder Widget. This allows you to use Connection.state function to know which state your stream is in. Then you can run your method only when the connection state has finished waiting